# Toilet/pipe Problem?

Tags: plumbing

I noticed this dried, sprayed looking, brown/yellowish stuff on my basement wall and looked up and it’s underneath one of the toilets.

[image: Stain on wall]

I then had someone flush the toilet and saw nothing leaking out from anywhere. I noticed a little darkness around the main toilet pipe and a few drips of same looking stuff on other pipe.

[image: Pipes]

Any idea of what this is or why it happened? 
Please let me know if pictures are not viewable. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I don’t know much about plumbing but am curious, since it did not leak when the toilet was flushed, could this occur when plunging the toilet only?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. That stain on the wall didn't just drip from above; it's clearly affected by something that was there (e.g. a desk). What was it? And, if you see no moisture now, it's probably historical.

Comment: I had some boxes there. It’s like it dripped/splashed on the box and then splashed on the wall. Moved in a little over a year ago. House is 16 yrs old.

Comment: What is that dark spot on the above floor around the drain pipe? Could the wax ring need to be replaced?

Comment: I was also thinking a leaking wax ring. +

Comment: I just noticed it and it was all dry. I cleaned it up and there’s been no leakage since but idk what the dark spot is where the pipe is. Is a wax ring an easy replace?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three possible explanations:

1. The wax ring under your toilet just wore out and needs to be replaced. This seems unlikely if your house is only 16 years old; a properly installed wax ring should last 20-30 years.
2. Your toilet is not seated securely. This can happen if the bolts are not tight. If you can rock the toilet at all, this is probably your problem. When the toilet gets loose, the seal with the wax ring breaks. In this case you'd want to remove the toilet, fix the wax ring (or replace it with a new one) and then reinstall the toilet, being sure to tighten the bolts all the way but not overtighten.
3. At some point water pooled on your bathroom floor. (There could be lots of reasons for this: Someone took a shower with the curtain open, the faucet overflowed, someone tipped over a bucket, etc.) The water found its way down through the toilet flange hole. It picked up dirt along the way, hence the yellowish color.

Based on the information available, it's hard to say which of these three scenarios, if any, is the cause. If I were you, I wouldn't do anything at this point. I would keep observing: Go down in your basement once a week and see if you see (or smell) anything new near the stain. If you don't see signs of change, this was probably a one-time event, like water pooling on the floor, that you don't need to worry about again.

I'd also check to see if there still is water pooling on the bathroom floor. Check especially behind and alongside the toilet; it's possible the toilet tank is leaking, or the water supply line is leaking. But if you can't feel any water anywhere on your floor, then you most likely don't have an active problem.

You could replace the wax ring if you want. It's cheap (wax rings cost under 3 dollars) and relatively easy. But if I were you I wouldn't bother at this point because -- unless the toilet is loose -- I doubt the wax ring is the problem.

For what it's worth, I can't think of anything that could be wrong here that would result in catastrophic damage. Worst case, you have a small leak in your drain system somewhere, you caught it early and it would have to be left unchecked for months or years before it caused real damage. Best case, this was caused by a one-time event in the past that will never recur.

If you were suspecting leaking from a water supply line, I'd tell you to be more worried, because if that were to burst it could do significant damage very quickly. Not so with a drain line in this type of situation. The fact that the leak is over unfinished basement makes it even less concerning.

Answer (score 0):

To replace a wax ring, you have to remove the toilet, remove the old wax ring, clean the flange and replace the toilet with a new wax ring. There are a few thicknesses of wax rings so depending on the placement of the flange will determine the thickness of the wax ring needed. If the flange is recessed too far below the floor, you may need to use a double wax ring to make a good seal. The toilets are fairly heavy and require some expertise to shut off the water, redo the floor flange bolts and reset the toilet. It is not a hard job just a heavy and messy job. Have a few pairs of rubber type gloves on hand since the wax is hard to get off your hands. One last thing, do not tighten the floor flange bolts too much or you will break the toilet.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice everyone. I think at this point I am going to keep observing, I don’t have any water pooling on the floor, in the bathroom anywhere/see any leaks anywhere. If it occurs again, I’ll be back on here and figure out the best course of action.